# SQL querying multiple tables for information

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a little dilemma in joining data from 4 tables in one SQL query, I am using MySQL for the DB part and would appriciate any help you can give me.

Here is the task...

I have for tables with columns and data

```
Sale            Items        Owner        Salesman
--------------  -----------  -----------  --------------
*Salesman_id    Item_type    *Owner_id    *Salesman_id
*Owner_id       Item_color   Owner_name   Salesman_name
Buyer_id        *Owner_id
Price
```

I want to query these tables on the columns I have marked with emphases text. So I can get result like

Item type, Item color, Owner name, Salesman name, Salesman number.

I have gone through a countless number of iteration trying to achieve this both with JOIN and nested queries without sufficient result.

Comment: That looks pretty straight forward. Perhaps it's the table layout that doesn't fit what you want to do, so that's why you can't get the result that you expect? It looks like you are selling owners, not items, i.e. a sale is a connection between a salesman and an owner, so you can only sell every item that an owner has, not specific items. Perhaps you should have a connection between a sale and items instead of a sale and an owner?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a one-to-one relation you can use inner join

```
SELECT i.Item_type , i.Item_color ,o.Owner_name,sm.Salesman_name,sm.Salesman_id
FROM Salesman sm 
INNER JOIN Sale s ON (s.Salesman_id = sm.Salesman_id )
INNER JOIN Owner o ON (s.Owner_id=o.Owner_id)
INNER JOIN Items i ON (i.Owner_id=o.Owner_id)
```

If there is one -to- many try with Left join

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT Item_type, Item_color, Owner_name, Salesman_name, Sale.Salesman_id FROM Items
  INNER JOIN Owner USING(Owner_id)
  INNER JOIN Sale USING(Owner_id)
  INNER JOIN Salesman ON Salesman.Salesman_id=Sale.Salesman_id
```

why doesn't the Items table have a primary key?

Comment: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING(Owner_id) INNER JOIN

Comment: i just edited: removed the `ON` before `USING` and changed Salesman_number to Sale.Salesman_id

Answer (score 0):

A solution when we're **not** joining, and you want it them to just display their values, you can do something like (I know this doesn't directly answer OP's question, but I'm getting there...)

```
   SELECT sale.`salesman_id`,sale.`owner_id`,
          items.`order_id`,
          owner.`owner_id`,
          salesman.`salesman_id`
   FROM `Sale` sale,
        `Items` items,
        `Owner` owner,
        `Salesman` salesman
```

And that should return everything.

However, your question states that we are joining. Could you put some data into something like [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) so I have some visual representation? and a brief summary of what you're trying to accomplish - as in where you want the joins?